# Mostrar inputs ao clicar em "Incluir"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma div chamada "produto", dentro dela de inicio tenho 4 inputs text:

```html
<input type="text" name="produto"> <input type="text" name="quantidade"> <input type="text" name="valor"> <input type="text" name="subtotal"> <input type="submit" value"Incluir">
```

Quero que ao clicar em "Incluir" apareça mais 5 inputs dentro dessa div:

```html
<input type="text" name="codigo_produto"> <input type="text" name="ean"> <input type="text" name="un_medida"> <input type="text" name="descricao"> <input type="text" name="tributos">
```

Obs.: Só pra comentar,que não posso usar ID pois estarei utilizando a função que clona a div em jquery.

Grato..

Comment: Você não pode usar `id="produto[]"` ?

Comment: Define um classe do tipo inputHidden com display: none, adiciona essa classe nesses inputs, cria uma inputShow com display: block, quando voce quiser mostar os input voce apenas adiciona o inpitShow com o js para todos os elementos com inputHidden

Comment: "apareça mais 5 inputs", qual o problema com append do jQuery? Ou você só quer exibir algumas entradas escondidas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que seria isso que você precisa, fiz o exemplo abaixo veja se te atende.

Resumo do codigo:
Os inputs que você quer que aparece após clicar em incluir, foi adicionado a classe do css: escodido assim: class="escondido".

Criei a classe no css: *Obs se vc usar Bootstrap pode substituir a classe escondido por Hidden que tem a mesma função.

.escondido{
display:none;
}

Adicionei o método ao botão com o evento click (Pode ser usado em outras chamadas do sistema ai vai de você )
Foi usado JQuery, o método remove todos as classes:Escondido de todos os inputs que a possuem, Fazendo com que os inputs apareçam

Espero que te atenda.

```js
$("input[type='submit']").click(function() {
$(".escondido").removeClass("escondido");
});
```

```css
.escondido{
  display: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="produto">
<input type="text" name="produto"> <input type="text" name="quantidade"> <input type="text" name="valor"> <input type="text" name="subtotal"> <input type="submit" value"Incluir">
  
 <!-- Campos que ficarao escondidos -->
<input type="text" class="escondido" name="codigo_produto"> <input type="text" class="escondido" name="ean"> <input class="escondido" type="text" name="un_medida"> <input type="text" class="escondido" name="descricao"> <input type="text" class="escondido" name="tributos">
</div>
```

Comment: isso mesmo, deu certo, não tinha pensado nessa lógica,  funcionou direitinho..Valeu amigo..muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("form").submit(function(e) { { 
    e.preventDefault();

  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     $('#produto').append('<div><input type="text" name="input_' + i + '"></div>');
  }
 });
```

Comment: Poderia explicar o que esse código faz e pq ele funciona, de forma breve?

Comment: ele simplesmente adiciona a quantidade de inputs na tela ao submitar o formulário.